# how to export the return table data to a csv file using react js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

I am new to React js.

I am trying to export the returned tabular data to a csv file on a button click.

```
let names = [
  {firstName: 'John',lastName: 'Cena'},
  {firstName: 'Rey',lastName: 'Mysterio'},
]

const App = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      {names.length > 0 && <table> //table renders only when array has elements 
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>   //setting headers
        <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
        {names.map((name,index) => {       //mapping for individual rows
          return (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{name.firstName}</td>
              <td>{name.lastName}</td>
            </tr>
          )
        })}
        </tbody>
      </table>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I want to create a button called export, and it should then download the table data thats being returned to a csv file.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A library like react-csv will help you to export data to a csv file easily, here is an example :

```
import { CSVLink, CSVDownload } from "react-csv";
    
let names = [
  {firstName: 'John',lastName: 'Cena'},
  {firstName: 'Rey',lastName: 'Mysterio'},
]

const App = props => {
  return (
    <>
      <CSVLink data={names}>Download me</CSVLink>;
      // or
      <CSVDownload data={names} target="_blank" />;
    </>
  );
};
```

For more information about the library visit: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-csv

Comment: How do i return the same when someone uploads the file?

Comment: Can you explain more cuz this library is used only to export data in format csv

Comment: Sure, so lets say I have an upload button, when the user clicks on the upload file and uploads the file which we exported above, and when he uploads a file how do I display the same data in tabular format?

Comment: Ah okey, I understand your need. You can use another package to read csv file like react-papaparse or you can use this method explained in the article : https://dev.to/theallegrarr/read-csv-files-in-react-apps-without-installing-any-package-hn7